# Why does "let" not evaluate, but just gives me #<promise>

Tags: scheme, racket

Something simple as this:

```
Welcome to DrScheme, version 4.2.3 [3m].
Language: Lazy Scheme; memory limit: 128 megabytes.

> (let ((x 2) (y 10))
   (+ x y))

#<promise>

>
```

I press enter for the let expression, and it gives me the `#<promise>`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says `Language: Lazy Scheme;`.  I'm sure this means that you're using a variant of scheme that runs lazily - *i.e.* it doesn't evaluate an expression until the result is required.  The way scheme will manage this internally will be by using scheme's `promise` mechanism - instead of returning the result of an expression, a `promise` to calculate the result later is returned.  You should be able to get the result explicitly by calling `force` against this promise.

Here are a couple of references:

- [Wikipedia article on lazy evaluation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

  [Scheme r5rs on `force` and `delay`.](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_562)

A non-lazy scheme will behave in the way you expect.

HTH

Comment: Hmm, I did a quick search on SO a few days ago and most people suggested DrHaskell as an IDE. On the language selection, that was the only one with Scheme in the name so I just chose that one. I guess it was the top most one "Module."  Thanks